# Having trouble with 2 default gateways

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, gateway, wired-networking

I got trouble with having 2 Default Gateways and when those 2 are configured it just causes too many problems like loss of Internet connectivity

Here is my IP config for each adapter

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.2(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.1

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.137.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.137.3
```

is there any way I can fix the Internet connectivity while having both Default Gateways also I want both of them to be functional

and I use Ethernet for file transfer and extending screen

Comment: Why do you have 2 default gateways? The rule is, if you have 2 default gateways they need to both be able to reach the same destinations.

Comment: @Appleoddity There is one wifi which clearly it's for my internet and then another one which is for file transfer and project display option from windows

Comment: Then you need to stop using a default gateway on the network that doesn’t have an internet connection. You’re not using DHCP so simply leave the gateway address blank.

Comment: Oh so I can just leave that blank and I don't need the gateway for file transfer?

Comment: Assuming all devices you are talking about are on the same network (192.168.137.x) then yes, you don’t need a default gateway. This is your most likely scenario. If you were on a larger network with multiple subnets you would need to still remove the default gateway and instead use static routes.

Comment: Thanks and no it's just both PCs connected with LAN directly

Answer (score 1):

The default gateway is *the* default. A routing table says, essentially "to go to this set of networks, go here; for this other set; contact this other one; anything else, send to the default".